# Какая разница между методом экземпляра и статическим методом?

Tags: javascript, классы, методы

В данный момент занимаюсь изучением классов и интересует такой вот вопрос.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какая разница между методом экземпляра и статическим методом в классе Javascript? Синтаксис этих методов мне известен, как вызвать и как применить тоже знаю. Вопрос в том, в каких случаях и какой вид метода лучше применять? Статьи про классы не дают внятного объяснения о разнице между этими методами, кроме как о их правильности написания в коде.

Comment: Если методу что-то делает с конкретным экземпляром, то это метод экземпляра. Например метод push у массива изменяет текущий экземпляр массива, так что логично что это метод экземпляра.  С другой стороны Array.isArray не привязан ни к какому конкретному массиву, это статический метод класса

Comment: Ну, допустим взять метод массива reverse, его типа тоже можно сделать статическим. Пока я вижу разницу только в быстроте выполнения кода (в классе то же самое), но я подумал что разница не только в этом и поэтому задал этот вопрос. 

`let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Array.reversed = function (a) {
    let res = []
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        res.push(a[i])
    }
    return res;
}

Array.reversed(arr);
arr.reverse();`

Comment: Статический метод можно скопировать в экземпляр и наоборот, поэтому о скорости вряд ли стоит думать. Технической разницы между ними нет, это просто функции. Статический метод сам является методом экземпляра объекта-функции, написанного с большой буквы.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev но это же не значит, что я должен беспорядочно создавать и применять эти методы там где и как мне вздумается. Разница в применении всё-таки должна быть, т. е. если создается статический метод в классе, то должна же быть причина, почему именно статический, а не экземпляра.

Comment: Ну допустим технически можно всё, но будет неудобно. Поэтому пишут так чтобы было удобно. Ну и, кстати, ваш `Array.reversed` делает не то же самое что `arr.reverse`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну применительно к данному массиву в результате разницы особой нету, а так да, они делают не то же самое. Просто технически можно создать и такой статический метод. И если дело только в удобстве, тогда ситуация начинает проясняться. Видимо эту грань мне ещё предстоит понять. :)
Спасибо за ответ, с меня плюс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статические члены класса всего лишь удобный способ объявить некоторый функционал и/или некоторое состояние в именованном пространстве имен.

К примеру метод `parseInt` есть и в `window.parseInt()`, но логичнее иметь его в пространство имен `Number`. Это, в том числе, позволяет проще ориентироваться в `API`, ведь когда мы ищем некоторую функцию и знаем что это касается числа, скорее всего справочник мы откроем на странице [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Какой бы ожидал нас ужас, имея статические методы `isArray(), isInteger(), ...` десятков классов в глобальном объекте.

Статический метод не имеет привязки к `this` объекта, так как класс является шаблоном(и реализацией), а не реальным объектом. Соответственно статические члены не могут обратиться к полям и ничего сказать о состоянии реального объекта. Но реальная польза статических членов - взаимодействие с экземплярами всего класса.

К примеру мы создаем некоторый тип объектов, где только один может быть активен. Кроме того, мы не знаем о существовании объектов и задачей является использовать единственно доступный метод включения/выключения подсветки активного элемента. Можно создать статические поля и метод взаимодействия со всеми экземплярами класса, а объекты, в свою очередь, будут менять общее состояние всего класса.

```js
// Этот класс предоставляет только один общедоступный статический метод взаимодействия со всеми экземплярами
class SomeClass {

  // Общее свойство/состояние для всех экземпляров в пространстве имен SomeClass
  // Мы используем приватные поля, чтобы пользователи не смогли наделать глупостей и сломать наш объект
  // Обращение к приватному статическому свойству SomeClass.#activeElement - вызовет ошибку Private field
  static #activeElement = { classList: { remove: (_) => null, add: (_) => null } }
  static #show = null

  constructor(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Здесь мы можем обратится к статическому свойству, только через SomeClass
      // т.к this привязан к конкретному экземпляру класса

      // Текущий экземпляр ничего не знает о своем родственном элементе, 
      // но знает что должен удалить подстветку старого элемента и подсветить себя.
      SomeClass.#activeElement.classList.remove('active')
      // Текущий элемент становится активным для всех экземпляров класса.
      SomeClass.#activeElement = el
      if (!SomeClass.#show) return
      SomeClass.#activeElement.classList.add('active')
    })
  }

  // Из этого общедоступного метода мы имеем доступ к текущему состоянию наших объектов
  static showActive(state) {
    // Здесь this имеет привязку к SomeClass.
    // По другому можно написать и так SomeClass.#show - ничего не изменится
    this.#show = state
    // Вариант доступа через SomeClass
    SomeClass.#activeElement.classList[state ? 'add' : 'remove']('active')
  }
}

// Нам даже не нужна ссылка на экземпляры класса - Просто создаем объекты.
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((d) => new SomeClass(d))

// Некоторый клиентский код может ничего не знать о существовании объектов и не знать когда они будут созданы,
// но использовать статический метод, когда пользователь желает отобразить подсветку активного элемента.
let h = false
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
  () => SomeClass.showActive(h = !h)
)
```

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 8px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

div.active {
  outline: 4px solid #e91e63;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Кликни любой элемент и нажми подсветку. Независимо от состояния подсветки, последний "кликнутый" элемент будет всегда сохранен в статическом свойстве
</p>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<br>
<button>Покажи/спрячь активный div</button>
```